# Calculate retention for daily users with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, metrics, pgadmin, retention

I am trying to calculate the daily retention of users login sessions using pgadminIII / postgresql.

`table1` has `user_id`, `first_login_date`, `last_login_date`

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (user_id numeric, first_login_date date, last_login_date date);

  INSERT INTO table1 (user_id, first_login_date, last_login_date) VALUES (12346, '2010-06-01', '2010-06-02'),
(67890, '2010-03-01', '2010-03-10'),
(67890, '2010-03-01', '2010-03-10'),
(90123, '2010-08-01', '2010-08-15'),
(45678, '2010-08-01', '2010-08-20'),
(76543, '2010-07-01', '2010-07-01');
```

`table2` has `user_id`, `session_id`, `login_date`

```
CREATE TABLE table2 (user_id numeric, session_id numeric, login_date date);

INSERT INTO table2 (user_id, session_id, login_date) VALUES
(12346, '8764', '2010-06-02'),
(67890, '4657', '2010-03-05'),
(90123, '3945', '2010-08-09'),
(45678, '20845', '2010-08-02'),
(67890, '29384', '2010-03-07'),
(90123, '3424', '2010-08-12'),
(45678, '349284', '2010-08-10');
```

There are some duplicates in `table1`. 
Because of this, I am unsure if my query to calculate the users that have 2-day retention and 5-day retention is correct.

The query that I am using for the 2-day is:

```
SELECT table1.user_id, first_login_date, table2.login_date,
(table2.login_date - table1.first_login_date) as datediff, FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table2.user_id = table2.user_id WHERE
(table2.login_date - table1.first_login_date) = 1;
```

which gives the result of 7 users with 2-day retention

However, if I add the distinct clause, such as:

```
SELECT distinct table1.user_id, first_login_date, table2.login_date,
    (table2.login_date - table1.first_login_date) as datediff FROM table1
    JOIN table2 ON table2.user_id = table2.user_id WHERE
    (table2.login_date - table1.first_login_date) = 1;
```

I get the result of 3 users with 2-day retention.

I have consulted [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492842/how-to-calculate-retention-month-over-month-using-sql), [HERE](http://blog.forcerank.it/sql-for-calculating-churn-retention-reengagement) and [HERE](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/use-self-joins-to-calculate-your-retention-churn-and-reactivation-metrics.html) regarding the calculation of daily retention, and I am unsure if my technique is giving me the correct result. For instance, to calculate the DAU, would a `self-join` be more appropriate.

Given the data in `table1` and `table2` are my 2-day retention results accurate using my defined query?
Is there an optimized way to calculate this retention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining `table2` to itself:

```
ON table2.user_id = table2.user_id
```

Do the `distinct` in a subquery:

```
select distinct on (t2.login_date)
    user_id,
    first_login_date,
    t2.login_date,
    t2.login_date - t1.first_login_date as datediff
from
    (
        select distinct *
        from t1
    ) t1
    inner join
    t2 using (user_id)
where t2.login_date - t1.first_login_date = 1
 user_id | first_login_date | login_date | datediff 
---------+------------------+------------+----------
   12346 | 2010-06-01       | 2010-06-02 |        1
   45678 | 2010-08-01       | 2010-08-02 |        1
```

Comment: This query does not filter the distinct users. With this `join` it produces more lines than my input.