# 'LAG' function not working in Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to find out the `retention rate` by using the following query on Amazon Redshift:

```
    WITH t AS (
SELECT ga.ownerid,
       DATE_PART('month',ga.creationtime) AS month,
       COUNT(*) AS item_transactions,
       LAG(DATE_PART('month',ga.creationtime)) OVER (PARTITION BY ownerid ORDER BY DATE_PART('month',ga.creationtime)) = DATE_PART('month',ga.creationtime) -interval '1 month' OR NULL AS repeat_transaction
FROM flx2.groupactivities ga
  JOIN auth.members m ON ga.ownerid = m.id
WHERE ga.activitytype = 'assign'
AND   ga.groupid NOT IN (SELECT groupid
                         FROM (SELECT groupid,
                                      COUNT(DISTINCT memberid)
                               FROM flx2.grouphasmembers
                               GROUP BY groupid
                               HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT memberid) = 1))
AND   ga.ownerid IN (SELECT memberid FROM auth.memberhasroles WHERE roleid = 5)
AND   ga.ownerid NOT IN (SELECT memberid FROM auth.memberhasroles WHERE roleid = 25)
GROUP BY ga.ownerid,
         DATE_TRUNC('month',ga.creationtime)
ORDER BY ga.ownerid,
         DATE_TRUNC('month',ga.creationtime)
   )
SELECT month
      ,sum(item_transactions) AS num_trans
      ,count(*) AS num_buyers
      ,count(repeat_transaction) AS repeat_buyers
      ,round(
          CASE WHEN sum(item_transactions) > 0
             THEN count(repeat_transaction) / sum(item_transactions) * 100
             ELSE 0
          END, 2) AS buyer_retention
FROM   t
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
WITH t AS (
SELECT ga.ownerid,
       DATE_TRUNC('month',ga.creationtime) AS month,
       COUNT(*) AS item_transactions,
       LAG(DATE_TRUNC('month...

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: ORDER/GROUP BY expression not found in targetlist;

Execution time: 0.29s
1 statement failed.
```

I believe there's something wrong with the `LAG` function here, but I'm not quite sure. I got this query from the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492842/how-to-calculate-retention-month-over-month-using-sql) and I modified it according to my requirements.

Would someone please be able to help me out with what's going wrong here?

I appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: Please do not tag questions for Redshift with `postgresql`. Redshift may be based on Postgres but it is different enough

Answer (score 0):

A quick look, but `lag` by itself is not an aggregate function so `repeat_transaction` would need to be included in the `group by`.